# symbolic link without expanding $HOME or "~"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, admin, ln

the basic idea is that I want to link to path that's relative to $HOME, rather than explicitly expand the $HOME variable, as I want to make sure the link works on multiple machines, e.g.,

when I do

```
ln -s ~/data datalnk
```

I want it to be directed to directory `/home/user/data` on one machine which has a user `$HOME` of `/home/user`, and to `/home/machine/user/data` on another machine which has a user `$HOME` of `/home/machine/user/data`.

I cannot create a symbolic link on the second machine using

```
ln -s /home/machine/user /home/user
```

because I don't have the permission to do that, and I cannot `link` relative paths as the two machines have different hierarchies of directories.

anyideas on possible ways to fix or circumvent this?

EDIT:

what I am really trying to accompanish is to make the same link work on two macihnes, where the targets have the same directories in terms of their relative path to $/HOME only, not their absolute path, and not their relative path to the link either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make symlinks dynamic in this way is to use a relative path instead of an absolute path. In other words, don't start your path with `/`.

For example:

```
cd
ln -s data datalnk
```

At runtime your app or script will need to refer to `~/datalnk` or `$HOME/datalnk`.

You haven't really said what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't really tell whether I'm solving your problem or suggesting that you need to go at it a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I have stated in the question that it seems that relative path doesn't work because the link and the target are generately having different relative path depth in between. what I am really trying to accompanish is to make the same link work on two macihnes, where the targets have the same directories in terms of their relative path to `$/HOME` only.

Comment: But what are you actually trying to accomplish by this? Do you want to let the user choose where to put her/his data directory instead of forcing them to use a particular place like `~/data`? Where do you want to place this symlink, anyway?

Comment: it has nothing to do with other users. It's just that I am working on the same hg repository on two different machines that I don't have root privilege of, but I need to share the same data on the two machines without including them in the hg repo (too big to put in). I figured that I can simply link them in the hg repo while putting the links in a Dropbox directory to sync them outside of hg. Just to make the workflow on two machines seamless!

Comment: Interesting. Are you running it under the same user account which contains the `~/data` folder?

Comment: unfortunately not, as I mentioned in the post, one is `/home/username1`, the other is `/home/machinename/username2`...

Comment: And you're running it under more different users like `username3` and `username4`?

Comment: I don't understand why don't have your software simply expand `$HOME/data` on startup. In both cases you'll get the correct thing. It's exactly what `$HOME` is for.

Comment: that's definitely a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

tl,dr **it won't work**

You can use an escaping mechanism such as single-quotes to get the `~` *into* the symbolic link:

```
> cd ~
> echo hello > a    
> ln -s '~/a' b
```

However, `~` is a *shell expansion* and is not understood by the filesystem (actually, to the filesystem it's "just another character"). This is a good thing -- want the file-system layer to know about environment variables, as `~` is generally determined by `$HOME`?

```
> ls -l b
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             3 Oct 27 17:39 b -> ~/a
> ls b
ls: b: No such file or directory
```

You *could* still "manually" look at said symbolic link entries (as done with `ls -l`), but that would have to be done in a non-transparent fashion by a program (think of a ".LNK" in Windows). As can be seen, the filesystem *just doesn't understand `~`*.

Happy sh'ing.

Comment: indeed "home directories" are an entirely userspace concept.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: It can't be done directly. Symbolic links are plain text files, no extensions are performed. If you can't formulate a fixed relative or absolute path to the place you are referring, you can't symbolically link to it.

You can build a script to put links to appropriate directories in appropriate places, but the best way depends on your application.